# remove - under a condition

Tags: r, stringr

I have the following types of strings with `-` and want to remove `-` under a condition.

```
str1 = "strings -123"
str1_2 = "strings - 123"
str2 = "strings 123-456"
str2_2 = "strings 123- 456"
str3 = "strings 123-"
str3_2 = "strings 123 -"
```

The desired out is following

```
out_str1 = "strings 123"
out_str1_2 = "strings 123"
out_str2 = "strings 123-456"
out_str2_2 = "strings 123-456"
out_str3 = "strings 123"
out_str3_2 = "strings 123"
```

How can I remove `-` only when there are no numeric values before or after -?

```
x <- c(
  str1 = "strings -123",
  str1_2 = "strings - 123",
  str2 = "strings 123-456",
  str2_2 = "strings 123- 456",
  str3 = "strings 123-",
  str3_2 = "strings 123 -"
)
```

Comment: You're also removing spaces, but not all of them. In fact, `str2_2`'s dash should be removed but you kept it.

Comment: I want to make it consisting of "strings", single space and numeric, when there is only numeric. When there is numeric - numeric (like str2 or str2_2), I want to make a string with "string", single space, "numeric-numeric"

Comment: `gsub('(?<=[A-z])(?=\\d)', ' ', gsub(' -| |-$', '', x), perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Can your `strings` contain more than one word and also hyphen in between to be replaced by white space?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it:

```
stringr::str_remove(examples, "(?<!\\d)-|-(?!\\d)")
```

In the example, we're matching for (not a digit preceding a dash) *or*  (not a digit following a dash). If either one is true, then it evaluates to true, and removes the dash.